# Get substring from twitter source in R

Tags: r, dataframe, substr

I have a dataframe in which one column is the twitter source, however, right now it looks messy. To clean it I would like to extract only: Twitter for iPhone, Twitter for Android, etc.

So I want to extract all text between ">" and "<" [image]

Thank you

Comment: We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, please provide a [reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are some tips on how to ask a good question.

Comment: you should have a look to `html_text` from `rvest` package to extract the text from html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` plus backreference:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(source = '<ref=""http://twitter.com/download/iphone"rel=""nofollow"">Twitter for iPhone </a>')
```

Solution:

```
sub('.*nofollow"">(Twitter for \\w+\\b).*', '\\1', df$source)
```

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract` and positive lookbehind and lookahead:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df$source, '(?<=nofollow"">)[\\w\\s]+(?=\\s</a>)')
```

Result:

```
[1] "Twitter for iPhone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strsplit function and pass it the "<" symbol

Comment: First off, this should be `str_split`(with the underscore) and the result is not the desired output: `str_split(df$source, "<")
[[1]]
[1] ""                                                                                    
[2] "ref=\"\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\"rel=\"\"nofollow\"\">Twitter for iPhone "
[3] "/a>"`

Comment: It works splitting a string based on the parameter that you pass it. E.g. if you have "example-test" and you call it with strsplit(string,"-", fixed=T) it returns 2 values "example" and "test". So in this way you can also call in a recursive way, so can call it in the output of a previous strsplit

Comment: Agata please provide a concrete example relevant to the OP's use case, just as @ChrisRuehlemann has done.  This will make your answer more helpful to the OP.